# Does WS-Security protocol require SSL

Tags: encryption, ssl, ws-security

Does WS-Security protocol require SSL for encrypting messages and for authenticating clients using certificates, or is WS-Security protocol independent of SSL and thus it doesn't use SSL to perform the encryption and certificate authentication?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSL (and newer TLS) is apparently an alternative to WS-Security so I doubt it to be the case that ws-security *requires* SSL. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Security#Transport_Layer_Security_.28Without_WS-Security.29

Comment: They are different protocols.

Comment: @user437291 most welcome. @GregS that comment was me being sarcastic at someone who commented that they weren't. Since someone removed their comment my comment got misinterpreted so I removed mine as well :)

Answer (score 2):

You can encrypt and sign with WS-Security. That said SSL is a much more understood protocol with a [very low overhead](http://www.imperialviolet.org/2010/06/25/overclocking-ssl.html).  `SSL/TLS is not computationally expensive any more`

So you should consider using SSL first and WS-Security if needed. WS-Security is an option if you use authentication based on security token formats, such as SAML, Kerberos, or X.509.